# Does converting an int into a hex always results in a different number?

Tags: c

I was asked to write a code that converts an integer and turns it into a hex.
I managed to write the code. However, every time I enter the same number I always get a new hex value, is this normal?

Also, why the values are different from expected? for example, if I enter "1" isn't the hex value supposed to be "01"?

The value that I get is something like "95f9a4".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char str[5] = { "\0" };
    printf("Please enter a num:");
    scanf_s("%d", &i);
    sprintf_s(str, "%x", i);
    printf_s("%x", str);
}
```

Comment: `str` is a pointer and you're printing in the last line this memory addres (in hex format) which changes every time you run the program

Comment: @AlejandroBlasco: `str` is an array, not a pointer, but when the array name is passed to `printf()`, it is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 4):

You have unnecessary code, which resulted in more places to make a mistake.

After `sprintf_s(str, "%x", i)`, `str` contains the hex representation of `i`. Then `printf_s("%x", str);` prints out the `str` *pointer* as a hex number.

The minimal fix is to change the latter line to `printf_s("%s", str)` to output the *content* of the string `str`.

The better way would be to just directly print out the hex value, without going through `str` at all. Replace both lines with just `printf_s("%x", i)`.